# Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JFrame.setVisible(boolean)" because "this.secondFrame" is null

Tags: java, actionlistener

I really dont understand this error. what does it mean and how can i fix it?

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyClass implements ActionListener
{
JFrame firstFrame;
JFrame secondFrame;
JButton firstButton;

public MyClass()
{
    firstButton = new JButton("Convert Currencies");
    firstButton.setBounds(150, 100, 200, 50);
    firstButton.setText("Convert Currencies");
    firstButton.setFocusable(false);
    firstButton.setVisible(true);
    firstButton.setLayout(null);
    firstButton.addActionListener(this);

    firstFrame = new JFrame("Currency Converter");
    firstFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xD3D3D3));
    firstFrame.setSize(500, 700);
    firstFrame.setLocation(870,15);
    firstFrame.setResizable(false);
    firstFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    firstFrame.setVisible(true);
    firstFrame.setLayout(null);
    firstFrame.add(firstButton);

    JFrame secondFrame = new JFrame("Currency Converter");
    secondFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xD3D3D3));
    secondFrame.setSize(500, 700);
    secondFrame.setLocation(870,15);
    secondFrame.setResizable(false);
    secondFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    secondFrame.setLayout(null);
    secondFrame.setVisible(false);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == firstButton)
    {
        firstFrame.setVisible(false);
        secondFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
}
```

Whole error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JFrame.setVisible(boolean)" because "this.secondFrame" is null

Comment: You declared a local variable called `secondFrame` in your constructor and initialised that instead of initialising the field `secondFrame`.

Comment: So wheres the line i should change and how should i change it? (im a absolute beginner)

Comment: What @khelwood said. Take a look at `JFrame secondFrame = new JFrame("Currency Converter");` inside `public MyClass() { .. }` constructor. It declares *local variable* named `secondFrame` which is *separate* variable from `JFrame secondFrame;` *field* of your class (even if it has same name). What you want is to assign value to existing `secondFrame` so remove `JFrame` from `JFrame secondFrame = new JFrame("Currency Converter");` to prevent declaring new variable.

Comment: @jakob Take a look at how you have initialised ```firstFrame```. Same way you should follow for ```secondFrame```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create another variable of JFrame, when you have already declared secondFrame outside of MyClass.

Just remove the JFrame in front of the secondFrame since you have already declared it earlier.

Correct code:

`secondFrame = new JFrame("Currency Converter");`

Comment: Okay but didn't i do the excact same thing with the other frame firstFrame and the button firstButton? It works with those...  EDIT: Okay i get it now! Thanks!

Comment: No, for firstButton and firstFrame you have not added JFrame to them when you were initialising it. Since all 3 are already declared, there is no need to declare them while initialising.